# Jersey Service and Persistence Layers

Tags: java, rest, jersey, service-layer, data-layer

I'm am developing a simple Question and Answer service (Jersey JAX-RS). With this service, I've come up with the following resource so far (might increase).

- GET|POST -------------/questions
- GET|PUT|DELETE -- /questions/{id}
- GET|POST ------------ /questions/{id}/answers
- GET|PUT|DELETE - /questions/{questionId}/answers/{answerId}

This is my resource class with caters all of the above paths.

```
@Path("/questions")
public class QuestionResource {
    @Inject
    private QuestionService questionService;

    @GET
    ...<list of questions>

    @POST
    ...<a new question>

    @Path("{id}")
    ...<a question>

    @PUT    
    @Path("{id}")
    ...<update a question>

    @DELETE
    @Path("{id}")
    ...<delete a question>

    @GET
    @Path("{id}/answers")
    ...<list of answers>

    @POST
    @Path("{id}/answers")
    ...<a new answer for a question>

    @GET
    @Path("{questionId}/answers/{answerId}")
    ...<an answer for a question>

    @PUT
    @Path("{questionId}/answers/{answerId}")
    ...<update an answer for a question>

    @DELETE
    @Path("{questionId}/answers/{answerId}")
    ...<delete an answer for a question>
}
```

This has corresponding service and persistence layers - QuestionService/QuestionServiceImpl and QuestionRepository/QuestionRepositoryImpl. But, I'm bit confused as to which service and reposipotory I should put the methods that would be called to process the request of the last five. Should I put them all also to Question service and repository or to another classess - Answer service and repository?

I'm considering the latter due to Many-To-One relationship of Answer and Question (JPQL NamedQuery - SELECT a FROM Answer a WHERE a.question.id = :questionId). It would mean that I would have also AnswerService aside from QuestionService in my QuestionResource. Would that be alright.

Please enlighten me. Thank you.

Comment: I think you should put your method in the main resource, like if you want answers of a specific question then your main resource is questions and you should put method in question class and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Would you mind to explain why?

Comment: I think I shouldn't have included this "I'm considering the latter due to Many-To-One relationship of Answer and Question (JPQL NamedQuery - SELECT a FROM Answer a WHERE a.question.id = :questionId)." to my question. It looks irrelevant.

Comment: Ye, it's irrelevant, In restful APIs everything is a resource and when it comes to relation you consider a main resource and other resources. In your case can answers be a main resource without question or in another words which one of your resources depends on the other one.Absolutely your answer depends on question.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Please post your question and I'll accept it if I get no other reasonable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In restful APIs everything is a resource and when it comes to
  relation you consider a main resource and other resources or in
  another words resource and subresource.
- In your case **the answer is the subresource** because your answer resource can't be a main resource without question or in
  another words which one of your resources depends on the other
  one. Absolutely your answer depends on question